# RS232 transfert, python interprets my data as new line feed and cariage return

Tags: python, serial-port, newline, carriage-return

I currently am working with a microcontroller to set a communication between an ASIC and my PC. The ASIC sends data to the microcontroller through SPI and the microcontroller sends the data to the PC through UART (RS232).

I'm using python to "record" the data (which is continuously sent through UART). Please note that the python program used wasn’t coded by me, but by some other people I can’t get in contact with. Moreover, I haven’t got any experience with python.

Here is an example of the data I’m sending through UART:  (the program is counting)

```
255 -> start byte
0 -> 1 bytes of data
0 -> 1 bytes of data
0 -> 1 bytes of data
8 -> 1 bytes of data
0 -> stop byte

255
0
0
0
9
0

255
0
0
0
13 ->This is what I don’t want. I’m sending 10 but that 13 is added by python
10
0
255

255
0
0
0
11
0
...
```

As shown above, when one byte of data is 10, a 13 is recoded/added. Based on what I’ve read about carriage return and new line feed, I’m guessing this error has to do with python interpreting my data. I’ve tried reading the “serial” driver (or whatever it is I’ve read), but couldn’t find anything to disable such “interpretation of my data”.

Would any of you know where I should be looking at? Ask for more details if it’s not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing: 
OutputFile = open(filename, "w") to OutputFile = open(filename, "w**b**")